# How to use a batch_size of Keras tensor at the model building time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use an external program as a custom operation.
Because automatic gradient would be not available, I wrote the code to provide gradients by using numerical methods. However, because it have to compute the batch_size number of derivatives,
I wrote it to get batch_size from the shape of x.

Following is an example using numpy function as an external program

f(x) = np.sum(x**2)
(In fact, for this simple numpy function, no loop over batch_size is necessary. But, it is written for general external function.)

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(x):
    # without using numpy, use external function
    # assume x shape = (batch_size,3)  
    batch_size= x.shape[0] 
    input_length = x.shape[1]
    # assert input_length==3
    yout=[] # shape should be (batch_size,1)
    gout=[] # shape should be (batch_size,3) 
    for i in range(batch_size):
        inputs = x[i,:] # shape (3,)
        y = np.sum(inputs**2) # shape (3,)
        yout.append(y) # shape (1,)
        # compute differences
        dy = [] 
        for j in range(len(inputs)):
          delta = np.zeros_like(inputs) 
          delta[j] = np.abs(inputs[j])*0.001
          yplus = np.sum((inputs + delta)**2) # change only j-th input
          grad = (yplus-y)/delta[j] #shape (1,) 
          dy.append(grad)
        gout.append(dy)            
    yout = tf.convert_to_tensor(yout,dtype='float32') # (batch_size,)
    yout = tf.reshape(yout,shape=(batch_size,1)) # (batch_size,1)
    gout = tf.convert_to_tensor(gout,dtype='float32') # (batch_size,) 
    gout = tf.reshape(gout,shape=(batch_size,input_length)) # (batch_size,1)
    def grad(upstream):
        return upstream*gout
    return yout, grad 

x = tf.Variable([[1.,2.,3.],[2.,3.,4.]],dtype='float32')
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = custom_op(x)
tape.gradient(y,x)
```

and found it works.

However, when I tried to use it in the keras model , for example,

```
def construct_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,)) #input array 
    x      = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
    outputs = custom_op(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    optimizer = 'adam'
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
    return model 

model = construct_model()
```

it gives errors
because kerasTensor "inputs" does not have specified batch_size.
I tried to specify batch_size as "tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,),batch_size=2)".
However, it also raises errors because of the use of kerasTensor.

How should I change the custom_op to be compatible with keras?

Comment: Is batch_size unknown at the time of construction of the model?

Comment: The batch_size is not known at the time of construction of the model. I tried to specify 
 tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,),batch_size=10). However, this also raised problem at calling custom_op(x). Because the values of x are not known at the time of construction, external program call custom_op(x) raises error.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this error. My error is raised by the first line of custom_op saying `KerasTensor` doesn't have `numpy()`. (TF 2.7.0)

Comment: I am sorry that I did not wrote a actual working code. As you wrote, if one replace the input as a KerasTensor, I have to change the code to use x.shape. However, it does not resolve the problem because calling custom_op(x) requires x to be values while KerasTensor at the time of construction does not have values . Maybe, a custom operator using KerasTensor should be written in different ways.

Comment: I tried to see if I could make it work with some conditional on `x.shape.is_fully_defined()`. I get this error message: 
# TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense/BiasAdd:0', description="created by layer 'dense'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add`

Comment: or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried to make additional custom layer which use custom_op. However, it still give errors. It seems that my custom_op cannot be used for keras model construction and should be used only in eager mode of tensorflow.